# Manage often used code in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-snippets, vsx

When programming a big project, you often need the same pieces of code in different pages. calling methods, returning references, ...

Now, I always need to open a page, and copy paste parts from that. but I'm getting tired of that. There should be a better way to list very often used code. I've read about snippets but they seem a lot of work. How do you manage that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snippets are not a lot of work if you use one of the handy snippet-easing extensions to Visual Studio. I happen to like this one http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/B08B0375-139E-41D7-AF9B-FAEE50F68392 by Matt Manela. Once it's installed, you can right-click a block of code and make it into a snippet. You can also set up replacements just like when you do an if or for block with the built-in snippets.